# Why does Decimal not support high Doubles?

Tags: swift3, numbers, decimal, nsdecimal

```
let highDouble = 1.7976931348623e+308 // Just under Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude
print(highDouble) // 1.7976931348623e+308
let highDecimal = Decimal(highDouble)
print(highDecimal) // 17976931348623005696000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is not what I put in. For clarity, if I bring that back into a `Double`:

```
let newHighDouble = Double(exactly: highDecimal as NSNumber)!
print(newHighDouble) // 1.7976931348623e+52
```

So a magnitude of 308 was reduced to only 52! **What's going on here?** I thought `Decimal` could store extraordinarily large values, but it seems it can't even store what a `Double` can!

---

Short snippet: `Double(exactly: Decimal(1.7976931348623e+308) as NSNumber)!`

Comment: It's precision vs. scale. Here's an [discussion for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net) but apply to Swift as well. You don't use `Decimal` to store very big numbers, you use `Decimal` when you need exact decimal floating point numbers, like in financial calculations. Use an external library like `bignum` when you need huge numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***What's going on here?***

For me it seems to be a bug of Swift Standard Library.

It is not clearly described in the [documentation of `Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal), but `Decimal` (in Objective-C, it's `NSDecimal`) is the basis of `NSDecimalNumber` and [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) clearly states:

> An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa
>   x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits
>   long, and **exponent is an integer from –128 through 127**.

(Bold style added.)

So, your `highDouble` cannot be represented as `Decimal`. In my opinion, `Decimal.init(_: Double)` should be a failable initializer, or at least it should return `Decimal.nan` (or some appropriate non-number value, if any) for numbers which cannot be represented as `Decimal`.

This behavior happens because [current implementation of `Decimal.init(_: Double)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Decimal.swift) is setting the calculated decimal `exponent` to internal `_exponent` without checking its bounds. You can find that `Decimal(1e256)` returns `1.0000000000000008192` (it's `1.0000000000000008192e0`), and `52` is `308-256`.

Better send a bug report to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) or [swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org).

---

***Why does Decimal not support high Doubles?***

*I thought Decimal could store extraordinarily large values, but it seems it can't even store what a Double can!*

If this is your main concern, it's described in the comment of Code Different.